# How to start activity to selected fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-pageradapter

how to start activity to selected fragment?

this is my fragment list and i need start actvity to topTygodnia() how do it?

```
    val adapter = ViewPageAdapter(supportFragmentManager)

    adapter.addFragmenr(Sciana(), "Posty")
    adapter.addFragmenr(Wydarzenia(),"Wydarzenia")
    adapter.addFragmenr(Konto_zarzadzanie(), "Ustawienia")
    adapter.addFragmenr(topTygodnia(), "top tygodnia")
    adapter.addFragmenr(TopMiesiaca(), "top miesiaca")
    adapter.addFragmenr(OstatnieWiadomosci(), "powiadomień")


    viewPager.adapter = adapter
    nawigacja.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
```

Comment: BTW: you should work on sticking to one, best widely used naming convention. These are here to make life easier. Your code will be really P.I.T.A. for others to read after some more lines added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`topTygodnia` fragment has index of 3 (zero-based index). So you can use ViewPagers `currentItem` property to set the currently selected page:

```
viewPager.currentItem = 3
```

---

**Note**: the good approach is to stick to class naming conventions: class name should start with a **capital letter**, consist of **english words** and have **Camel Case Style**. For example use `WeekTopFragment` instead of `topTygodnia`, `AccountManagementFragment` instead of `Konto_zarzadzanie`.